# Time Complexity of ICollection.Count and Array.Length Property

Tags: c#, arrays, icollection

I was wondering if the [ICollection.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection.count?view=net-7.0#system-collections-icollection-count) is just a lookup (Time Complexity in O(1)) or iterates over the Collection. Same for the [Array.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-7.0#system-array-length) property.

Also, if I have the option to use both, which one is better to use?

Comment: Well ideally you shouldn't be using `ICollection` because it's a non generic interface. Prefer `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.Length` is a O(1) operation - the length is stored and simply read-n-returned to the user.

`ICollection.Count` is a member of an interface. Interfaces are contracts and hence do not contain implementations.

So, anyone could write any implementation they want, so the complexity is undefined in a general case.

However, it is **strongly implied** — by (a) the member `Count` being a property and by (b) the interface itself being a separate entity from `IEnumerable<>` — that it should have O(1) complexity as well.

Comment: "Interfaces ... do not contain implementations" [well, they can but please don't do that](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/)